# WSO2 ESB validate on empty/missing XML tags

Tags: xpath, wso2-esb

I am trying to make a validation of XML requests on missing or empty XML tags. I used this code

```
<filter description="Validate material" regex=".+"
    source="//E1MARAM[not(MATNR)] | //E1MARAM/MATNR[not(text())]">
    <then>
        <log category="WARN">
            <property name="/material"
                value="validation-empty tag MATNR send back to SAP" />
        </log>
        <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
            value="500" />
        <makefault version="soap11">
            <code value="soap11Env:VersionMismatch" xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
            <reason value="Missing SAP parameter" />
            <detail>MATNR</detail>
        </makefault>
        <respond />
    </then>
</filter>
```

which beatifically checks the XML tag `//E1MARAM/MATNR`

My problem is that this works only when the tag is empty.
    It seems like the Filter mediator with reqex .+ and xpath `//E1MARAM[not(MATNR)]` does not meet the condition and thus the check does not work

Any idea why? or perhaps another idea how to better validate in WSO2 ESB on missing XML tags or values without XSD? a XSD schema cannot be used, as the XML request does not have a fixed structure - typical for SAP iDoc

Comment: I managed to find a workaround. by using COUNT  <filter description="Validate material" regex="1.0"
    source="count(//E1MARAM[not(MATNR)] ) + count ( //E1MARAM/MATNR[not(text())])">

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to check for an not empty string ''.  This will resolve to false both when empty and when missing. Also, you do not have to use the regex to check, you can just use xpath. If you give the filter mediator an xpath expression it will resolve it as if checking a boolean.

```
<filter description="Validate material" xpath="not(//E1MARAM/MATNR!=''") >
```

This will return true if the element is either empty or does not exist. It will return false if there is a text value.